# Is there anyway to have TestCafe Studio select the client certificate when the browser is launched?

Tags: html, user-interface, automation, certificate, testcafe

I would like to automate a web page using TestCafe Studio. However, every time the web page is launched you have to select a certificate to validate yourself before the page is loaded. Is there anyway that TestCafe Studio can select the certificate? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can authenticate a user with a client certificate using the [Request Hook](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402842/guides/intermediate-guides/intercept-http-requests#create-a-custom-request-hook).

Create a RequestHook like:

```
const target = /https:\/\/my\.secure\.host/
export class MyRequestHook extends RequestHook {
  constructor() {
    super(target)
  }

  onRequest(event) {
    // add keys to request
    Object.assign(event.requestOptions, {
      ...keys
    })
  }

  onResponse() {}
}
```

where keys is

```
const keys = {
  key: fs.readFileSync(USER_KEY),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(USER_CRT),
  ca: fs.readFileSync(CA_CRT)
}
```

the constants USER_KEY, USER_CRT, CA_CRT are paths to the PEM formatted keys/certs.